# Adding an ID column to a SpatVector in R?

Tags: r, terra

I've been rewriting an R script so it uses `terra` instead of `raster` and other packages, and I've managed to do it all except for one painfully simple task - adding an ID column to a SpatVector.

My code up to that point is simply:

```
AOI_path <- "N:/R/AOI_polygon.shp"
AOI <- project(vect(AOI_path), "epsg:27700")
AOI <- buffer(AOI, -15)
```

I can easily do what I originally did, and then convert the result into a SpatVector, as below:

```
AOI <- st_transform(read_sf(AOI_path), crs=27700)
AOI <- st_buffer(AOI, -15)
AOI <- AOI[!st_is_empty(AOI),]
AOI <- mutate(AOI, ID=row_number())
AOI_vect <- vect(AOI)
```

But I'd prefer to do it all within `terra` if possible. I've tried multiple methods like: `AOI$ID <- 1:nrow(AOI)`, or making a dataframe and adding it to the SpatVector, but I usually get this error: `Error: [[[<-,SpatVector cannot set these values`.

Answer (score 4):

If `AOI` is of class `SpatVector`, your first attempt should work without problems:

```r
library(terra)
#> terra 1.6.7

v <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra") |> vect()

class(v)
#> [1] "SpatVector"
#> attr(,"package")
#> [1] "terra"

v[["ID_new_v1"]] <- 1:nrow(v)
v$ID_new_v2 <- 1:nrow(v)

v
#>  class       : SpatVector 
#>  geometry    : polygons 
#>  dimensions  : 12, 8  (geometries, attributes)
#>  extent      : 5.74414, 6.528252, 49.44781, 50.18162  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#>  source      : lux.shp
#>  coord. ref. : lon/lat WGS 84 (EPSG:4326) 
#>  names       :  ID_1   NAME_1  ID_2   NAME_2  AREA   POP ID_new_v1 ID_new_v2
#>  type        : <num>    <chr> <num>    <chr> <num> <int>     <int>     <int>
#>  values      :     1 Diekirch     1 Clervaux   312 18081         1         1
#>                    1 Diekirch     2 Diekirch   218 32543         2         2
#>                    1 Diekirch     3  Redange   259 18664         3         3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative.

`v$ID <- seq.int(nrow(v))`